# Https connection, TLS hangs and eventually fails SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: ssl, https, curl, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to correctly diagnose an issue where the server i have access to doesn't seem to be able to contact another server on the internet over port 443:

```
~$ curl https://mydomain.co.uk -vvv
* Rebuilt URL to: https://mydomain.co.uk/
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mydomain.co.uk (1.2.3.4) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to mydomain.co.uk:443 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to mydomain.co.uk:443
```

I've read that this could be because of incompatible ciphers. So i tried it on a different server on a different network but this time the connection was made successfully:

```
~$ curl https://mydomain.co.uk -vvv
* Rebuilt URL to: https://mydomain.co.uk/
*   Trying 1.2.3.4...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to mydomain.co.uk (1.2.3.4) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=NA; ST=Some Place; L=Some City; O=MyCompany; OU=Technology; CN=*.mydomain.co.uk
*  start date: Mar 15 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 13 12:00:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "mydomain.co.uk" matched cert's "mydomain.co.uk"
*  issuer: C=US; O=AniCert Inc; OU=www.anicert.com; CN=NioTrust RSA CA 2019
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: mydomain.co.uk
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 25 Feb 2019 17:30:02 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 154
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://www.mydomain.co.uk
< 
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host mydomain.co.uk left intact
```

The two servers i tried the `curl` command from are both the same, the networks they're on differ. The two servers i have access to are running Ubuntu 18.04. I don't have access to the remote server that they're both trying to connect to. I need to be able to pin point what the issue is/could be.

So it's not the cipher. What else could cause the TLS handshake to hang like this?

Cheers,
Ankur

Comment: What is different about the networks? What is the site you are trying to connect to?

Comment: The server that is having issue connecting to the site is in a network that i have no control over. The other server that does work is at home. The site i'm trying to connect to is a well known transport company... not sure i can say much more than that.

Comment: You should ask the network administrators at the site you are having trouble. They may have a firewall in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved. It was due to the ip being blacklisted. Once it was taken off the connection established successfully.

Comment: Strange that the initial connection was made OK.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, that is odd. Since the TCP packets contain the originating IP information, you'd think that the remote server would prevent the TCP connection from being made.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a coincidence, but I had a similar error today. The server process picking up the connection somehow got half-stuck. Sometimes it picked up allright, the other times it left the client waiting indefinitely at exactly the same point as you have here. Had to kill -9 this server process.

Comment: I can suggest that to the owners of the site, but it seems to be a networking issue.

Comment: Seems also similar to this issue: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/2299. Maybe there is a MTU problem?

Comment: I tried altering the MTU but that doesn't help either

Comment: Try some variations `curl -v --ciphers DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 https://example.com`  , `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443` , `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -mtu 1478 -no_ticket -msg -cipher DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256`, `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -mtu 1478 -no_ticket -msg`